# Context menu in GWT- Hide and show

Tags: gwt

I have created a context menu, that pops up on right click on the parent SimplePanel. How can I remove the ContextMenu from the Simple Panel on click event on the parent (Simple Panel) in GWT?

To create : Right click on your screen to see the context menu and then left click to see it gone.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a context menu long back and here I blogged it

http://codeinventions.blogspot.in/2014/07/context-menu-or-right-click-handler-in.html

```
rootPanel.sinkEvents(Event.ONCONTEXTMENU);
 rootPanel.addHandler(
     new ContextMenuHandler() {
         @Override
         public void onContextMenu(ContextMenuEvent event) {
             event.preventDefault();
             event.stopPropagation();
             popupMenu.setPopupPosition(event.getNativeEvent().getClientX(),
                 event.getNativeEvent().getClientY());
             popupMenu.show();
         }
     }, ContextMenuEvent.getType());
```

Comment: I have created a custom ContextMenu, don't want to use existing one.

Comment: @Forkmohit CSS might different. You can use event related codes.

Answer (score 0):

If you using the GWT PopupPanel use the auto hide feature:

```
new PopupPanel(true);
```

That will close the popup on every click event that not hit the PopupPanel.

Comment: Ok and whiche component do you use?

Comment: I used ui:binder to create a custom panel.